# Choosing resistors for LDO LDK130

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo

What is the Vadj voltage that should be considered while choosing a resistor for the LDO **LDK130**?
Data sheet link: [LDK130 low quiescent current very low noise LDO](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/ldk130-974161.pdf)

Comment: Can be considered 0.8VDC. You could see it in the table at p. 10.

Answer (score 1):

If we look on page 10 of the datasheet, you get the electrical characteristics page. Here, it tells you that the Vadj pin should be around 800mV (784 min, 800 typical and 816 max). Another part to note would be Iadj it states should be max 1uA. This should help you determine the resistor values you need.

**NOTE:** I usually put in pictures of datasheet tables when I quote parts from them but for some reason it wasn;t letting me upload them today!

Comment: Why electrical characteristics not the absolute maximum readings ?

Comment: You should always try and avoid the maximum. It gives you zero room for error. And quite often, most devices won't work to the best of their abilities at these extremes. If you want your device to work reliably, stick to those values on page 10.

Comment: "absolute maximum" do you drive at the top speed of your car all the time? Do you run everywhere at the fastest? Leave room for the variation necessary.